# Why is an SVG node removed during SolidJS JSX rendering?

Tags: javascript, jsx, solid-js

I'm building a custom dropdown, where each option has an SVG icon and a label.
While the icon of the selected element is rendered initially, the SVG icon is removed upon expanding the select. Whenever a new option is selected, it's rendered again until the select is expanded again. There's no change to the `value().icon` state upon expansion.

Within the JSX there's no condition applied to the `svg` in `value().icon` either:

```jsx
      <button
        onClick={() => setExpanded((prev) => !prev)}
      >
          <span>{value().icon}</span>
          <span>{value().label}</span>
          <svg />
      </button>
```

[Reproducible Example Playground](https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/c5f53b29-2db5-4ce3-97bb-67c154e8a26a)

[image]

Based on browser debugging (breakpoint on node removal on the `svg`), I believe something odd happens around [dom-expressions L78](https://github.com/ryansolid/dom-expressions/blob/main/packages/dom-expressions/src/universal.js#L78). The `value` in `parent.appendChild(value)` seems to correctly contain the `svg` on first selection (when it prevails), but also on expansion (when it's removed), which I can't make sense of.

Comment: It's not specifically SVG. If you used `<span>4</span>`, `<span>5</span>` and `<span>6</span>` as icons, every time you expand, the node will be removed from the button and appended to the option (the 'icon' node is not cloned, just moved to the option).

Comment: Right, good spot. If I use `value().value` as an example though, it persists. So I'm not quite sure what it's related to if not to the node type. Can you elaborate on what you mean by _not cloned, just moved to the option_?

Comment: If you do `parent1.appendChild(node); parent2.appendChild(node)`, then parent1 loses the child, because child goes with parent2. Based on your code, you were effectively generating just one instance of `<Icon .../>` for each color, then you try to append one node inside the button, and also the same node inside one of the options. So the button doesn't have that icon node anymore.

Comment: One work around is, instead of using one element like `icon?: JSXElement`, use a function that can create elements repeatedly, like `icon?: () => JSXElement`

Comment: Thanks a lot, excellent explanations, I wasn't aware of the `appendChild` behavior. This explanation makes sense, the workaround works fine. Off the top of my head, I'd think this is an issue with the JSX/DOM rendering runtime, as I'd expect to be able to pass in an array of `option` objects and then refer to the properties in as many locations a I wish, without having to worry about the implementation under the hood. Do you agree?

Comment: I think it's a limitation of Solid JS, because it tries to create a real DOM node rather than virtual DOM like React. (I found some info while I wondered about [Can I clone an element?](https://github.com/solidjs/solid/discussions/794)). In your original code, if you use `<span>{value().icon.cloneNode(true)}</span>` (and ignore TypeScript warnings/errors) you'll see that it indeed behaves like a regular DOM element. In React, repeating a child like `{child}{child}{child}` won't cause a problem, because the conversion to the real DOM is done later.

Comment: If you modified your original code to use `<span>2{value().icon}3{value().icon}4{value().icon}</span>`, you'll see that the icon appears only once, after 234. Again it has to do with repeated appendChild. I guess repeating `{value().value}` is fine because it is a string and not a DOM element, and the strings only get converted to DOM nodes later.

Comment: Thanks for doing the research and helping me wrap my head around it! Happy to accept it as answer too, if you want to post. Just one thing, with `<span>2{value().icon}3{value().icon}4{value().icon}</span>` it's not always after 234 (wasn't able to make sense of the order yet), but importantly it's always only displayed once, see [here](https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/fa48a6dc-0faf-4731-87e5-cb44ec62b800).

Comment: You are right. And I can't predict in which order the icon will appear either. But the important thing is of course, the child will only end up in one position.
I think SolidJS keeps a record of "which child does this parent have" and append it one by one. If it decides that the 2nd, 3rd, etc. parents don't need to update, then the child will end up in the 1st parent (because the 2nd parent etc. did not try to execute their "appendChild" method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would copy the code from the playground to that it's reproducible in the future, but I added some comments in the code.

```
import { createSignal, For, JSXElement, Show } from "solid-js";
import { render } from "solid-js/web";

function Select(p: {
  options: { label: string; value: string; icon?: JSXElement }[];
  selectedIndex?: number;
}) {
  const props = {
    selectedIndex: 0,
    ...p,
  };

  const [value, setValue] = createSignal(props.options[props.selectedIndex]);

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = createSignal(false);

  return (
    <div
      onFocusOut={(e) => 
        // don't process onFocusOut if the focus is in a child element (e.g., option button click)
        !e.currentTarget.contains(e.relatedTarget as Node) && setExpanded(false)
      }
    >
      <button
        onClick={() => setExpanded((prev) => !prev)}
      >
          <span>{value().icon}</span> {/* try to append the icon */}
          <span>{value().label}</span>
          <svg
            fill="#000000"
            height="1rem"
            width="1rem"
            viewBox="0 0 330 330"
          >
            <path
              id="XMLID_225_"
              d="M325.607,79.393c-5.857-5.857-15.355-5.858-21.213,0.001l-139.39,139.393L25.607,79.393
    c-5.857-5.857-15.355-5.858-21.213,0.001c-5.858,5.858-5.858,15.355,0,21.213l150.004,150c2.813,2.813,6.628,4.393,10.606,4.393
    s7.794-1.581,10.606-4.394l149.996-150C331.465,94.749,331.465,85.251,325.607,79.393z"
            />
          </svg>
      </button>
      <Show when={expanded()}>
          <ul>
            <For each={props.options}>
              {(option) => (
                <li>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      setValue(option);
                      setExpanded(false);
                    }}
                  >
                    {option.icon && <span>{option.icon}</span>} {/* try to append the icon again */}
                    <span>{option.label}</span>
                  </button>
                </li>
              )}
            </For>
          </ul>
      </Show>
    </div>
  );
}

function Icon(props: {color: string}) {
  return (
    <svg
      fill={props.color}
      height="1rem"
      width="1rem"
      viewBox="0 0 512 512"
    >
      <g>
        <polygon points="256,0 72.115,256 256,512 439.885,256   " />
      </g>
    </svg>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Select
      options={[
        {
          icon: <Icon color="#fc5614" />,
          label: "Red",
          value: "red",
        },
        {
          icon: <Icon color="#25b9e6" />,
          label: "Blue",
          value: "blue",
        },
        {
          icon: <Icon color="#79e625" />,
          label: "Green",
          value: "green",
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
}

render(() => <App />, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

In SolidJS, when you do for example `const par = <p>hello</p>` for example, `par` will refer to an actual DOM element (unlike in React which uses a virtual DOM node).

So, the restrictions of a real DOM node applies. For example, if you try appending a node to multiple parents, `parent1.appendChild(node); parent2.appendChild(node)`, the child node is not cloned, but simply moved to parent2. So, parent1 will not have the child because the child goes with parent2.

In each call to `App()`, for each color there is only one `<Icon/>` instance.
So effectively, when you show the options, what happens is that you have one DOM node that it tries to append to two different positions. But then the node can only appear in at most one place (because the node has at most one parent).

A workaround is to not use a single element like `icon?: JSXElement`, but rather to use `icon?: () => JSXElement` which will generate separate elements as many times as it is called, along with appropriate changes in other places (e.g. `icon: () => <Icon color="#fc5614" />` in App and `<span>{value().icon?.()}</span>` in Select).

This restriction doesn't apply to strings like `value().value`, probably because it is only converted to an actual DOM node much later (unlike JSX tags which are converted to actual DOM elements very soon in SolidJS).
The restriction also doesn't seem to apply to React, probably because it converts the virtual DOM nodes to real DOM pretty late (so something like `2{child}3{child}4{child}` will not give you a weird behavior in React even when the child is a JSXElement, but it can be quite weird in SolidJS).

Answer (score 1):

Your list is wrapped into a `Show` component, whenever state is updated whole list will re-created because hiding will destroy the previously rendered element.

If you check the output code, your component logic is complicated and svg part ends up tied to the `Show` element even though svg part is  pure:

```js
import { template as _$template } from "solid-js/web";
import { delegateEvents as _$delegateEvents } from "solid-js/web";
import { setAttribute as _$setAttribute } from "solid-js/web";
import { effect as _$effect } from "solid-js/web";
import { memo as _$memo } from "solid-js/web";
import { createComponent as _$createComponent } from "solid-js/web";
import { insert as _$insert } from "solid-js/web";
const _tmpl$ = /*#__PURE__*/_$template(`<ul>`),
  _tmpl$2 = /*#__PURE__*/_$template(`<div><button><span></span><span></span><svg fill="#000000" height="1rem" width="1rem" viewBox="0 0 330 330"><path id="XMLID_225_" d="M325.607,79.393c-5.857-5.857-15.355-5.858-21.213,0.001l-139.39,139.393L25.607,79.393
    c-5.857-5.857-15.355-5.858-21.213,0.001c-5.858,5.858-5.858,15.355,0,21.213l150.004,150c2.813,2.813,6.628,4.393,10.606,4.393
    s7.794-1.581,10.606-4.394l149.996-150C331.465,94.749,331.465,85.251,325.607,79.393z">`),
  _tmpl$3 = /*#__PURE__*/_$template(`<li><button><span>`),
  _tmpl$4 = /*#__PURE__*/_$template(`<span>`),
  _tmpl$5 = /*#__PURE__*/_$template(`<svg height="1rem" width="1rem" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><g><polygon points="256,0 72.115,256 256,512 439.885,256     ">`);
import { createSignal, For, JSXElement, Show } from "solid-js";
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
function Select(p) {
  const props = {
    selectedIndex: 0,
    ...p
  };
  const [value, setValue] = createSignal(props.options[props.selectedIndex]);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = createSignal(false);
  return (() => {
    const _el$ = _tmpl$2(),
      _el$2 = _el$.firstChild,
      _el$3 = _el$2.firstChild,
      _el$4 = _el$3.nextSibling;
    _el$.$$focusout = e =>
    // don't process onFocusOut if the focus is in a child element (e.g., option button click)
    !e.currentTarget.contains(e.relatedTarget) && setExpanded(false);
    _el$2.$$click = () => setExpanded(prev => !prev);
    _$insert(_el$3, () => value().icon);
    _$insert(_el$4, () => value().label);
    _$insert(_el$, _$createComponent(Show, {
      get when() {
        return expanded();
      },
      get children() {
        const _el$5 = _tmpl$();
        _$insert(_el$5, _$createComponent(For, {
          get each() {
            return props.options;
          },
          children: option => (() => {
            const _el$6 = _tmpl$3(),
              _el$7 = _el$6.firstChild,
              _el$8 = _el$7.firstChild;
            _el$7.$$click = () => {
              setValue(option);
              setExpanded(false);
            };
            _$insert(_el$7, (() => {
              const _c$ = _$memo(() => !!option.icon);
              return () => _c$() && (() => {
                const _el$9 = _tmpl$4();
                _$insert(_el$9, () => option.icon);
                return _el$9;
              })();
            })(), _el$8);
            _$insert(_el$8, () => option.label);
            return _el$6;
          })()
        }));
        return _el$5;
      }
    }), null);
    return _el$;
  })();
}
function Icon(props) {
  return (() => {
    const _el$10 = _tmpl$5();
    _$effect(() => _$setAttribute(_el$10, "fill", props.color));
    return _el$10;
  })();
}
function App() {
  return _$createComponent(Select, {
    get options() {
      return [{
        icon: _$createComponent(Icon, {
          color: "#fc5614"
        }),
        label: "Red",
        value: "red"
      }, {
        icon: _$createComponent(Icon, {
          color: "#25b9e6"
        }),
        label: "Blue",
        value: "blue"
      }, {
        icon: _$createComponent(Icon, {
          color: "#79e625"
        }),
        label: "Green",
        value: "green"
      }];
    }
  });
}
render(() => _$createComponent(App, {}), document.getElementById("app"));
_$delegateEvents(["focusout", "click"]);
```

You need to refactor your code in a way that state update does not trigger re-render for the svg. You can move your Select logic into smaller, well contained sub-components which provides proper isolation and can take advantage of memos and untracks in case state update spill onto them.

Solid does not use VDOM but compiles JSX into native DOM elements. The way it works is, Solid converts component's html structure into a template. Whenever state gets updated, it clones this template, fills with with dynamic values by evaluating them, and re-insert it to its parent component.

You can write any expression inside JSX. Chlid components are functions and they are compiled into function calls.

If you take a look at the output code, you will see svg is compiled into `_tmpl$5` and it is inserted into its parent under `Show`:

```
$insert(_el$, _$createComponent(Show, {
 // Snipped for brevity 
}))
```

This means, whenever `expanded` value changes the children of `Show` component will be re-created and re-inserted.

Normally you don't expect svg ends up being a child to `Show` because it comes before the `Show` in the DOM hierarchy and appears outside of it.  Your component logic unnecessary complex and convoluted causing some unexpected outcome, a  it is pointed in the accepted answer.

Don't rush for returning an element, take you time, build your logic, tame your state, only then return the element.

Here is an `Select` demo I wrote for another answer which might be helpful. It has basic functionality but can be improved easily:

https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/e58974e7-287f-4f56-8ab3-33787d93c629

Comment: Thanks for the answer. _hiding will destroy the previously rendered element._ I have a hard time following that as when the list is collapsed/hidden, the icon in the current selection persists (provided it's different from the previous choice). Regarding _smaller, well contained sub-components_, do you mind providing some high level view on how those components could look like? I have a bit of a hard time interpreting the output code, but I believe you're referring to the `_$insert`s after `_$createComponent(Show,...`, correct?

Comment: @tgikf I expanded the answer to answer some of your questions. Hope it helps.